# Subtraction error in Select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables, Table P and Table Q, with 10 rows and 2 rows each.

When I subtract (to find quantity) Table Q from Table P, by using the below code, subtraction affects to all (10 rows) row. Subtraction will be based on a batch number.

See the code I have used:

```
select p.batch,p.QTY-COALESCE(q.QTY,0) INSTOCK from 
(
select a.[ITEM CATEGORY NAME] cat,b.[ITM SUB CATEGORY NAME] subcat,c.[ITM BRAND DES] brand,d.[BTH NAME] batch,SUM(e.[INV QUANTITY]) QTY
from dbo.ITEM_CATEGORY a,dbo.ITM_SUB_CATEGORY b,dbo.ITM_BRAND_DES c,dbo.STK_BATC`enter code here`H d,dbo.INVENTORY_MASTER e
where 
a.[ITEM CATEGORY ID]=e.[INV CATEGORY] and
b.[ITM SUB CATEGORY ID]=e.[INV ITEM NAME ID] and
c.[ITM BRAND ID]=e.[INV ITEM BRAND ID] and
d.[BTH ID]=e.[INV BATCH ID] and
e.[INV PROCESS]='IN' 
group by a.[ITEM CATEGORY NAME],b.[ITM SUB CATEGORY NAME],c.[ITM BRAND DES],d.[BTH NAME],e.[INV BATCH ID]) AS p

CROSS APPLY

(select a.[ITEM CATEGORY NAME] cat,b.[ITM SUB CATEGORY NAME] subcat,c.[ITM BRAND DES] brand,d.[BTH NAME] batch,COALESCE(SUM(e.[INV QUANTITY]),0) QTY
from dbo.ITEM_CATEGORY a,dbo.ITM_SUB_CATEGORY b,dbo.ITM_BRAND_DES c,dbo.STK_BATCH d,dbo.INVENTORY_MASTER e
where 
a.[ITEM CATEGORY ID]=e.[INV CATEGORY] and
b.[ITM SUB CATEGORY ID]=e.[INV ITEM NAME ID] and
c.[ITM BRAND ID]=e.[INV ITEM BRAND ID] and
d.[BTH ID]=e.[INV BATCH ID] and
e.[INV PROCESS]='OUT' 
group by a.[ITEM CATEGORY NAME],b.[ITM SUB CATEGORY NAME],c.[ITM BRAND DES],d.[BTH NAME],e.[INV BATCH ID]) AS q
```

I know it is complex to understand, but you will get an idea about how I have coded. Is there any best method to subtract a table from another?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *substract Table Q from Table P*?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: The select contains `p.QTY-COALESCE(q.QTY,0)`.

Comment: where is the condition checking the batchnumber

Comment: Can you show some sample data and expected result.

Comment: Dear All, Thanks for yours consideration, I could solve problem by the below given query..

Answer (score 0):

Any reason the following wont work?

```
 select 
    p.batch, p.QTY INSTOCK 
from 
  (select 
        a.[ITEM CATEGORY NAME] cat,
        b.[ITM SUB CATEGORY NAME] subcat,
        c.[ITM BRAND DES] brand,
        d.[BTH NAME] batch,
        SUM(
          CASE 
            WHEN e.[INV PROCESS] = 'OUT' 
              THEN 
                 -e.[INV QUANTITY]
              ELSE
                e.[INV QUANTITY] 
            END) QTY
      from  dbo.INVENTORY_MASTER e
      join dbo.ITEM_CATEGORY a
         ON a.[ITEM CATEGORY ID]=e.[INV CATEGORY] 
      join dbo.ITM_SUB_CATEGORY b
         ON b.[ITM SUB CATEGORY ID]=e.[INV ITEM NAME ID] 
       join dbo.ITM_BRAND_DES c
           ON c.[ITM BRAND ID]=e.[INV ITEM BRAND ID]
       join dbo.STK_BATCH d
         ON d.[BTH ID]=e.[INV BATCH ID]
   where
       e.[INV PROCESS] IN ('IN','OUT')
         and
       e.[INV ITEM BRAND ID] = @EnterCodeHere
    group by 
       a.[ITEM CATEGORY NAME],
       b.[ITM SUB CATEGORY NAME],
       c.[ITM BRAND DES],
       d.[BTH NAME],
       e.[INV BATCH ID]) AS p
```

Comment: Thank you friend, You are brilliant..Thank you very much for saving my time with your brilliant idea..!!